# JavaScript Objects, Constructors, dot notation

Tags: javascript, object

I am taking an online javascript course through Oreilly School Of Technology. I have finished every lesson except for the last one. My instructor takes a while to get back to me with questions so I figured I would reach out to you for help. I don't want you to tell me the solution but rather help make sense of what I need to do.

Here is my example,

```js
window.onload = init;

var counter = 0;

function init() {
 var generateButton = document.getElementById("generateButton");
 var clearButton = document.getElementById("clearButton");
 var scene = document.getElementById("scene");

 generateButton.onclick = generate;
 //clearButton.onclick = clear;
}

function Box(boxID, name, color, xPos, yPos) {
 this.boxID = boxID;
 this.name = name;
 this.color = color;
 this.xPos = xPos;
 this.yPos = yPos;
}

function generate() {
 var boxes = [];
   
 var colorSelect = document.getElementById("color");
 var colorSelectOption = colorSelect.options[colorSelect.selectedIndex];
 var colorSelectVal = colorSelectOption.value;

 var boxesToGen = data.elements.amount;
  for (var i = 0; i < boxesToGen.length; i++) {
    if(boxesToGen[i].checked) {
     var boxesToGenVal = boxesToGen[i].value;

     for (var i = 0; i < boxesToGenVal; i++) {

    var div = document.createElement("div");

    var divClass = div.setAttribute("class", "box");
    divClass = div.setAttribute("id", counter);

    var addDivs = scene.appendChild(div);

    

    var name = document.getElementById("name");
    var boxName = name.value;

    div.innerHTML = boxName;

    counter++;

    newBox = new Box(counter, boxName, colorSelectVal, x, y);

    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (scene.offsetWidth-101));
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (scene.offsetHeight-101));

    div.style.backgroundColor = colorSelectVal;

    div.style.left = x + "px";
    div.style.top = y + "px";

    boxes.push(newBox);

    newBox.boxID = counter;

    console.log(boxes);
    

    div.onclick = display;

    }
   }
  }
  function display(e) {
   div = e.target;
   alert("boxID = " + newBox.boxID + " name = " + newBox.name + " color = " + newBox.color + " xPos = " + newBox.xPos + " yPos = " + newBox.yPos);
   console.log(getId);
 }
}
```

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
                
input#generateButton {
    margin-left: 15px;
}
                
div#status {
    margin-left: 15px;
}
                
div#scene {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
                
div.box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 90px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title> Final Project: Amazing Boxes </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <form id="data">
    <ol>
      <li>Pick a name for your Amazing Box: <br>
        <label for="name">Name: </label>
          <input type="text" id="name" size="20">
      </li>
      <li>Pick a color for your Amazing Box: <br>
        <select id="color">
          <option value="red">Red</option>
          <option value="orange">Orange</option>
          <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
          <option value="green">Green</option>
          <option value="blue">Blue</option>
          <option value="indigo">Indigo</option>
          <option value="violet">Violet</option>
        </select>
      </li>
      <li>How many Amazing Boxes do you want to create?<br>
        <input type="radio" id="five" name="amount" value="5">
          <label for="five">5</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="ten" name="amount" value="10">
          <label for="ten">10</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="fifteen" name="amount" value="15">
          <label for="fifteen">15</label><br>
      </li>
    </ol>
    <p>
      <input type="button" id="generateButton" value="Generate!">
      <input type="button" id="clearButton" value="Clear">
    </p>
  </form>
  <div id="scene">

  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f5670m68/2/

Here is the directions of the lesson. I am confused on one part in particular. It has to do with the display() function. The problem I am having is that when I click on a div, and do newBox.boxID, the result is 5 for every box. The code that is generated though contains div id="1", div id="2" etc. It looks like it always uses the last increment value.

Box(): create a constructor function named Box to create box objects for each box that's generated. The Box object will hold each property of a box, including its id, name, color, and x and y positions. Note that the id of each box must be unique, but the name isn't (you'll have multiple boxes with the same name).

boxes: an array of all the boxes. All boxes should be represented by  elements, and given the class "box" and a unique id. (Note that you can just use a number for an id if you want!).

counter: a global variable that keeps track of the number of boxes generated, which you can use to create a unique id for each box.

init(): the load handler.

generate(): the click handler for the Generate! button. This function generates the  elements that represent the boxes.

clear(): the click handler for the Clear! button. This function removes all the boxes from the scene, and resets everything so you can start from scratch.

display(): the click handler for each box. When the user clicks on a box, this function will show an alert with all the information about the box, including its id, name, color, and position.

Comment: Actually, I can't reproduce this. When I click on each box, the expected id is displayed as part of an `alert(...)` (it isn't always `5`).

Comment: I don't really know what all you said here; there are too many words. I get different IDs when I click on the box, in the pop-up alert.

Comment: You should get an alert when you click on each div. Try it again. The id's should all be the same now. I had some hacky code in there forcing the div id's to be different.

Comment: Ok but what is your question? I get different IDs.

Comment: The id's are all the same now if you click on each div. Try again.

Answer (score 0):

`newBox` (which you haven't declared anywhere in your code BTW) is a variable that you are continuously overwriting in your loop. It will hold the last value that you assigned to it, so if you generate 5 boxes and then click one, the `newBox` accessed in your `display()` function will be the last one you created (with an ID of 5).

It appears that you want to retrieve the box object that corresponds to the box that was clicked. The IDs you are assigning to your box elements is actually 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., so you can retrieve them from the array based on their ID (inside the `display()` function:

```
var clickedBox = boxes[getId];
```

You should also be incrementing `counter` at the *end* of your loop instead of in the middle. The way you had it, you were giving your box DIVs different IDs from the box objects.

And voilà, that part of your program should work.

https://jsfiddle.net/f5670m68/5/

(There was also an issue with you using your `x` and `y` variables before you gave them values. I've fixed that too.)

Comment: Why does `boxes` need to be an object? Whats wrong with an array of objects?

Comment: @zgood Well, since OP's IDs start at 1, that's not all that well suited for an array (although it would work), but more importantly, an object would allow OP to easily switch to non-numeric IDs (like `box1`, `box2`, which I think would be an advisable idea), but that would be trickier with an array.

Comment: makes sense. What just curious of your reasoning :) He could also use `data-id` as an attribute and store the counter there and recall it

Comment: @zgood Yes, I actually think a `data-` attribute would be preferable to using the element's `id` attribute, since that avoids conflict with other elements on the page.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Boxes does need to be an object. The lesson needs to follow the rules I outlined above.

Comment: My instructors comments:

How might display() (see instructions) use the .target event property to determine which div was clicked, 
then use its id as a cross-reference to find the index of the right Box() in the boxes array?

Comment: My instructors comments:

With the right Box() acquired, how might you use .dot notation to show all the properties in an alert?

Comment: I use dot notation but it always alerts an id of the last increment value. That's what I don't get. How does having a boxes array and global counter variable help accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce your error (all the ids were correct when I click on the divs)

What I think you need to do though is declare your `var boxes = [];` on a global scope (outside of the function it is currently in), then in your `display` function do something like this:

`var newBox = boxes[getId];`

This only works because you are setting your div ids to your `counter` value of your loop. (you really shouldn't set number only ids - this is invalid I believe)